# Extract string from one line to another line and replace

Tags: bash

I have a text file containing

```
CREATE TABLE attribute_type
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY...,
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT...
CREATE TABLE attribute_type_options
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY...,
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT...,
CREATE INDEX person_attribute_type_set ON table...,
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT...
...
...
```

I want to remove the lines starting with **CREATE TABLE table_name** word **table_name** and substitute the word **table** in the following lines, before finding a new line with **CREATE TABLE ...**

the output should be

```
CREATE TABLE attribute_type

ALTER TABLE attribute_type ADD PRIMARY KEY...,
ALTER TABLE attribute_type ADD CONSTRAINT...

CREATE TABLE attribute_type_options

ALTER TABLE attribute_type_options ADD PRIMARY KEY...,
ALTER TABLE attribute_type_options ADD CONSTRAINT...,
CREATE INDEX person_attribute_type_set ON attribute_type_options...,
ALTER TABLE attribute_type_options ADD CONSTRAINT...
...
...
```

I'm doing something ... but does not work !

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
   if [[ "$line" =~ ^CREATE.* ]]; then
      #would need to do something like
      #name=`awk '{print $3}' $line`
   else
      #sed -i 's/table/name/' $line
   fi
done < $1
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: what's the expected output for you example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes file `input`, does the substitutions, and writes to file `output`:

```
awk '{if (/^CREATE TABLE/) {name=$3} else sub("table", name);print}' input >output
```

#### How it works

- `if (/^CREATE TABLE/) {name=$3}`

  If the line starts with `CREATE ALTER`, then we save the third field as the name.
- `else sub("table", name)`

  Otherwise, we find the first occurrence of `table` on any line and replace it with the value saved in the variable `name`.
- `print`

  Lastly, we print out the line.

#### Example

Using the sample input from the current version of the question, the output generated is:

```
$ awk '{if (/CREATE TABLE/) {name=$3} else sub("table", name);print}' input
CREATE TABLE attribute_type
ALTER TABLE attribute_type ADD PRIMARY KEY...,
ALTER TABLE attribute_type ADD CONSTRAINT...
CREATE TABLE attribute_type_options
ALTER TABLE attribute_type_options ADD PRIMARY KEY...,
ALTER TABLE attribute_type_options ADD CONSTRAINT...,
CREATE INDEX person_attribute_type_set ON attribute_type_options...,
ALTER TABLE attribute_type_options ADD CONSTRAINT...
...
...
```

This code was written before the update to the question which added blank lines to the output.